# Roles and Permissions Issue

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard 1.3. I have created a content type named 'Product' and another one named 'Company'. Now, I want to allow some users to login to dashboard and create new company and product and edit ONLY company and product they had created.

So, I created a role and only gave permission to 'Edit Company' and 'Edit Product'. (eg:)
[image] 
Also gave 'Access admin panel' permission.
I created a user and assigned the newly created role to him.

But when I login as that user, I can see the full navigation. Shouldn't the navigation be just limited to the content items the user has the access to? Also this user has access to not only just create new 'Product' and 'Company', but also other content types for which I had not given any permission.

Please suggest how I can limit the access of this role to just the two content types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to 1.4. This issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Please file a bug on CodePlex.